# Vuejs 2 removing from array (splice) not animating with transition

Tags: animation, vue.js, vue-component, vuejs2

I have a vue component:

```
<transition-group name="list">
  <task v-for="task in tasks" v-bind:key="task.id" v-bind:task="task" class="list-task"></task>
</transition-group>
```

With a simple transition:

```
.list-task {
  transition: all 0.5s;
}
```

When I add an element to the `tasks` array with `unshift` I get a nice animation, where the existing elements are sliding down to make room for the new element.

However, when I remove an element from the array with `splice`, that element just just suddenly disappears.

How can I make it animate out like with adding an element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably forgot to specify the transition classes. This will give you a basic fade-out:

```
.list-leave-active {
  transition: all 0.5s;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

Please refer to the (excellent) docs on [Transition Classes](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html#Transition-Classes).

Comment: With that it works, take a look at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bvjfa9xk/9/
If you add a task, it animates, if you remove one it does not.